# What is the equivalent in Ubuntu to changing the Windows IPv4 configuration?

Tags: networking, ethernet, routing

The Windows IPv4 Ethernet settings (see image) have fewer options than Ubuntu wired settings and I am unsure what to change in order to mimic (if that is possible) the same change in Windows.

In Ubuntu 22.04 in Network Wired settings I can edit the profile that is connected to the device or create a new one. In the profile I can select the IPv4 Method as Manual and then add Addresses or Routes.

Separately I can change my laptop's IP (in my case the Wired IP) with the following command:

```
sudo ifconfig enp0s31f6 192.168.0.10 netmask 255.255.255.0
```

I tried to change the default gateway:

```
sudo route add default gw 192.168.0.1 dev enp0s31f6
```

That returned Network unavailable, but I think I am in the right direction with the command.

I am not sure which of these changes I need to replicate the settings change in Windows.

I think the Profiles in the settings are not equivalent to Windows "Use the following IP address". But I was also unsuccessful with the `ifconfig` and `route` commands.

The specific problem this question comes from is to connect my laptop to a device via Ethernet cable.

The device has a static IP address and if the IP address range of the computer is the same as the device you can access the device by entering the IP in a browser.

On Windows the manual shows that by setting the IP address, netmask, and default gateway in the settings you can access the device:
[image]

I have been unable to replicate this in Ubuntu as I cannot connect to the device in the browser.

Comment: Please see `https://netplan.io` and `https://netplan.io/examples`.

Comment: Please see Settings > Network: https://linuxconfig.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/04-set-configure-static-ip-address-ubuntu-18.04-bionic-linux.png